# IOS - Grouping Objects based on object value and show in UItableview sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Here is the json Response from Api 
[image: Json Response from Api]

Now I want to group the objects who has same date and show in UItableview with sections but I can't make the logic.

I want to make this look like the following Image

[image]

Kindly help me with this

Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342542/how-to-split-nsarray-into-uitableview-sections-alphabetically for the global logic + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426662/how-to-check-if-two-nsdates-are-from-the-same-day for the "grouping" logic by checking the day instead of the first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add each report to a dictionary of arrays using the date as the key. The number of keys is then the number of sections and each section size is the size of the associated array.

Comment: Thanks I have got the idea